# Crop text using CSS

Tags: css

I just want to know if there is a way to crop a text from beginning/left using CSS?

For example let I am having a text like this:

**I am a noob**

I want to hide the text I from the beginning only using CSS as I can not edit HTML there so that the text only show:

**am a noob**

Also fixed width also will not work for me as the text width may change to any short text in future.

Please help me.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try first.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hwdLu094/1/

```css
#Yo:hover
{
    display:none;
    
}

p{float:left}
```

```html
<p id="Yo">Yo</p><p>u are a noob</p>
```